# Are "tomorrow" and "morning" etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, loanwords

I know this is true for German and Spanish:

> Morgen morgen

and

> Mañana por la mañana

both mean "tomorrow morning". There may well be other examples too.

I wonder- since these languages have similar roots to English- is there any evidence that it has ever been the case in the English language too?

Comment: Although it's an interesting question, it is related to languages but not to English.

Comment: Sorry. I'll rephrase the question to tie it in.

Comment: @Urbycoz Unfortunately, I too think your question is off-topic.  It would make a great question for the Linguistics StackExchange, though!  There's a warm seat waiting there.  Have you considered committing [to the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics?referrer=1hZB241f0glMg1X13CJ1vg2)?

Comment: @Billare: I've committed to the proposal too. Looks good. I can see that this question was off-topic to start with (hence Alenanno's comment). Are you saying that you still think it is not related to the English language?

Comment: @Urbycoz Well, I think if the premise if your question were correct, it might be on topic: But AFAIK, the Germanic languages, of which English and German belong to, aren't Romantic languages.   So the connection isn't really there, which would make this more suitable for Linguistics.  I feel for you though, I'd love this question to be answered -- it's very interesting.

Comment: "Morgen morgen" is not something a German native speaker would say. It sounds awkward. "Morgen früh" or "Morgen vormittag" is normally used to express "tomorrow morning".

Comment: @Billare: I thought English was classed as a Romantic language, since I thought it was derived from Latin. It certainly has has "a substantial Romance influence", according to wikipedia.

Comment: @Urbycoz I guess you meant Romance languages, or Romanic languages; _Romantic_ means "relating to, or denoting the artistic and literary movement of Romanticism." As already said from Billare, English is not a [Romanic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Romance_languages), but a [Germanic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_languages).

Comment: @Bilare: You're right. I meant "Romanic"- sorry. I've removed that bit now anyway.

Comment: The title still has to be reworded to focus on English. And, as teylyn points out, the part about German is wrong. You might wish to just ask, "Are *tomorrow* and *morning* etymologically related?" and leave it at that. Otherwise, I'm not sure how this question is salvageable. (^_^)

Comment: Done and done. Cheers!

Comment: @Urbycoz: The incorrect German part is still in there...

Comment: I edited the question and changed Spanish phrase to *mañana por la mañana* instead of the unusual *mañana mañana*.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: The German part that was incorrect was removed.

Comment: @Urbycoz: I am confused; it still says "morgen morgen" in the question, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Kosmonaut If I change the German phrase to the one in more common usage, it defeats the purpose of the question. It may not be commonly said, but it is still grammatically acceptable.

Comment: @Urbycoz: It's that that "morgen morgen" is rare but acceptable -- it is never said and would be regarded as incorrect by native speakers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Tomorrow* comes from the Middle English, from the preposition *to* + *morrow*. *Morrow*, which is an archaic or literary word meaning "the following day," comes from Middle English *morwe*, from Old English *morgen*.

*Morning* has origin from Middle English, from *morn*. *Morn* comes from the Old English *morgen*, of Germanic origin.

At the end, both *tomorrow* and *morning* comes from the Old English *morgen*.