# Morrow vs. Tomorrow

Tags: differences

What's the difference between *morrow* and *tomorrow*? 
Why are there two similar words for the same meaning?

I noticed it in the title of a song of Michael Nyman, "Second Morrow", on Gattaca OST.

There is no sign that it was an ancient word.

Comment: Morrow is archaic, or no longer used

Comment: See _[Are “tomorrow” and “morning” etymologically related?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/22024/5822)_.

Comment: @mattacular “At last wearied with his cares Sam drowsed, leaving **the morrow** till it came; he could do no more.” —J.R.R. Tolkien, *The Lord of the Rings*

Comment: Morrow is archaic. While that doesn't mean "no longer used," it does indicate only a specialised application. [No longer used would be *obsolete*]

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for clarifying *archaic* vs *obsolete*; people often mistake those. You can see the transition from the vocabulary and phrasing of yesteryear to what is normal is our brave new millennium by comparing the various translations of Matthew 6:34. So take the KJV’s “Take therefore no thought for **the morrow**: for **the morrow** shall take thought for the things of itself. Sufficient unto the day is the evil thereof.” versus the NIV’s “Therefore do not worry about **tomorrow**, for **tomorrow** will worry about itself. Each day has enough trouble of its own.”

Comment: @AndrewLeach One might posit an ordering in *obsolete, archaic, poetic (out)dated, formal, informal, colloquial, slang, vulgar*.  Then there are things lik e *regional, jargon,*, and  *cant*, which don’t fit in that same set.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Andrew! I did mean to say "not often used"

Comment: @tchrist LOTR was published nearly 60 years ago and Tolkien uses lots of archaic language and many neologisms. This is fitting considering the nature of the fantasy world he was aiming to create but I'm not sure what your point is other than to provide an example of a use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Morrow* is "the day after"; *All Souls' Day is the morrow of All Saints' Day*. *Tomorrow* is simply 'today's morrow', as today was yesterday's morrow.

But, as others have said, *morrow* is currently little used compared with *tomorrow*.

Comment: [This Google N-Gram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=morrow%2Ctomorrow%2Cto-morrow&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is interesting: look at the crossing point.  Hmm, it might be better to use “the morrow” there; not sure.

Comment: @tchrist it is even more interesting, perhaps, when you reduce smoothing. At 0, it appears that another crossing point is about to occur.

Answer (score 0):

Morrow can be preceded by "Good" to form the phrase "Good Morrow" meaning "Good Morning".

It is still used today, but normally when the user wants to convey the impression of age, in a similar vein to how you would describe something as olde worlde.

Comment: Yes, *morrow* can meaning morning.  We did not used to have to resort to such reduplications  as “tomorrow morning”, because the morrow sufficed.

Comment: @tchrist isn't "reduplication" a reduplication?